# JTable with multiple elements in one cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I like to create a cell with a checkbox and one or two optional textfields.

If I click on the checkbox the textfields get visible. I tried to make an ASCII picture how it should look like:

```
[ ]
[X] [some string]
[X] [value1] [value2]
```

I know how to create a custom renderer but I am not sure how to return multiple elements. If I have a renderer for a checkbox I return only the JCheckBox:

```
class BooleanRenderer extends JCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer, UIResource
{
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                           boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        // doing some stuff...
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Thomas *et al.* are correct about distinguishing between the *model* and the *view*. Your model includes a boolean state and some corresponding text; your view is a `JCheckBox` that can be toggled and text that can be changed. You'll need both a renderer to display the current state of the model and an editor to allow changes to the state.

In this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table), the class `Value` holds the selected state and the underlying data, a `Double` value. The `DataModel`, which implements `TableModel`, manages a `List<Value>`. Note that both the editor and renderer use a common `java.text.DecimalFormat`. The related class [`java.text.MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) may be useful in composing your check box's text.

Answer (score 4):

You have to return a single component (which may be a JPanel in your case) which holds multiple other components.

See the follwing link [where a CellRenderer returns multiple entries](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2132279) (it is a ListCellRenderer, but the basics are the same).

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to represent that structure in your table model as well, i.e. the cell's value should already be a composite of the boolean flag and the other values.

Comment: Do I really need to do this? I can store all the values in one cell using a separator: checkbox|textfield1|textfield2. Maybe not very nice but that would work for me.

Comment: @PiTheNumber checkboxes etc. are representations, not values. Thus you can't store them using a separator. Of course you could use a string representation and parse that string every time you need to access a field but I'd say that creating a wrapper object would be far easier to write, understand and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Your Renderer class will have to return a parent component (as uhm said, probably a JPanel) on which you have your other objects: checkbox, textfields, etc.  Your tableModel will have to hold the values that the Renderer uses to portray each of those components.  For example, the model may be setup with a List of data objects, and each entry in the list holds a Boolean to indicate if the checkBox is selected, a String of the textField data, etc.  You cannot have a Table visually portray a useful Swing object if the associated model isn't storing it someplace.